# How to properly use ISession and session cookie in angular - asp.net.core app

Tags: c#, html, angular, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm middle in creating web app with frontend in Angular 7 and backend in ASP.NET.Core 2.1. On the server side I want to implement a simple session functionality. So in Startup.cs I configure session by using `AddDistributedMemoryCache()`, `AddSession()` and `UseSession()`. In server domain everything works fine. I have my session cookie and I have access to the session from controllers, repos etc. 
Problem is when I call a html method from another domain (from front in Angular). In HtmlRequest there is no info about cookie session so `HttpContext.Session.Id` is always different. Can I send value of My.Cookie to front to create cookie on front side by ngx-cookie-service? Then this cookie will be send automatically to backend in HtmlRequest. How I can access to this cookie from backend? I can only get cookie from request and request from frontend doesn't have My.Cookie. Or exchange My.Cookie between front and backend should happen automatically?

For now I created my own static storage as singleton service but I think it should be better solution with use `ISession`.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services
                .AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", policyBuilder =>
                    {
                        policyBuilder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                    });
                })
                .AddDistributedMemoryCache()
                .AddSession(options =>
                {
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                    options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder { Name = "My.Cookie", HttpOnly = false, IsEssential = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None };
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app
                .UseCors("MyCorsPolicy")
                .UseSession()
                .UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute("default",
                        "{controller}/{action}",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                });
        }
    }
```

FooController.cs

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FooController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult FooGet()
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(new { message = HttpContext.Session?.GetString("Message") ?? string.Empty, sessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult FooPost(dynamic clientSite)
        {
            string message = clientSite["message"];
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Message", message);
            return new OkObjectResult(true);
        }
    }
```

rest.server.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class RestServer {
  private url = `http://${location.hostname}:60000\\api\\foo`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public GetFoo(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }

  public PostFoo(message: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.url, {message});
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?